# c# nunit extent reports not getting screenshot, passing on exception

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, extentreports

i am trying to add screenshot to my extent report. 
I have applied exception to one of my test methods, and giving screenshot taking in exception.
Then i have called the screenshot function in teardown, so screenshot can show up in case it is failed. All good. but when i run the code that should be failing, it marks it pass due to exception, and in extent report it displays it as pass.How do i make it appear fail in extent report and display the fail screenshot with it?

namespace CreateTeamSpeed
{
    class ReportsGenerationClass
    {
        protected ExtentReports extent;
        protected ExtentTest test;

```
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    protected void Setup()
    {
        string path = TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory + "\\";
        string fileName = this.GetType().ToString() + "report.html";
        var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(path + fileName);
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
    }


    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeTest()
    {
        test = extent.CreateTest(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void AfterTest()
    {

        var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
        var stacktrace = string.IsNullOrEmpty(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace) ? "" : string.Format("{0}", TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace);
        Status logstatus;

        switch (status)
        {
            case TestStatus.Failed:
                logstatus = Status.Fail;
                test.AddScreenCaptureFromPath("screenshot.png");
                break;
            case TestStatus.Inconclusive:
                logstatus = Status.Warning;
                break;
            case TestStatus.Skipped:
                logstatus = Status.Skip;
                break;
            default:
                logstatus = Status.Pass;
                break;
        }
            var mediaModel = MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromPath("screenshot.png").Build();
            test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " + logstatus + stacktrace + mediaModel);


        extent.Flush();
    }


    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Test");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnK")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        driver.Quit();
    }


    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
       try{

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("qt")).SendKeys("Test");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnK")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        driver.Quit();
           }

    catch (Exception ex)

        {           
            ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile("screenshot.png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

        }


    }
}
```

}'''

Answer (score 0):

If you handle exception, it does not fail test.
To make it fail for external running tools, you can add call of Assert.Fail(); after screenshot.

Comment: aww yes, i have added Assert.Fail() as well , but now it has stopped taking screenshot.... before it was taking screenshot. Dont think there is any relation between the 2, but do you think something wrong with the calling function?

Comment: Where you added it? After screenshot taking method?

Comment: catch (Exception)

            {
                ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile("screenshot.png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
Assert.Fail();
            }

Comment: Thats weird. It works in my code. And when you remove Assert.Fail, it takes screenshot?

Comment: yes it does take screenshot. but then i come back to original problem

Comment: Okay, then try to put Assert.Fail(); after catch block, and return; before catch block

Comment: right so it fails and gives error at this line:     public void Test2()                         
 like, does it need some other type ?